# C# Unity Character jumps really weird

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

**Hello guys!**

I have a problem with my UNITY 5 code.

My character can jump but he jumps instantly and too fast.
It looks really weird.

I would greatly appreciate your feedback on my code!

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Gravity : MonoBehaviour {
    private float inputDirection;
    private float VerticalSpeed;
    private float gravity = -2f;
    private float speedmultiplier = 5f;
    private bool jump;

    private Vector3 moveVector;
    private CharacterController controller;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        controller = GetComponent<CharacterController> ();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        inputDirection = Input.GetAxis ("Horizontal");
        moveVector = new Vector3 (inputDirection, VerticalSpeed, 0) * speedmultiplier;
        controller.Move (moveVector * Time.deltaTime);

        if (controller.isGrounded) {
            VerticalSpeed = 0.0f;
            jump = true;
        } else {
            VerticalSpeed = gravity;
            jump = false;
        }

        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.X)) {
            if(jump == true) {
                VerticalSpeed += 25f;
        }
    }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try changing the vertical speed in your `else` to reflect a change over time.

Perhaps something like:

`VerticalSpeed += gravity * Time.deltaTime`

Instead of just setting it to gravity. You may need to play with your initial jump speed to get it to feel better, but this should start your jump fast-ish, slow down as you reach the top of the jump, and speed back up as you fall.